# Poles of $\large e^{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\fbox{1}$ If $z_0$ is a pole of $$f:U \subset \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$how to prove that $z_0$ can not be a pole of $\large e^{f(z)}$.

$\fbox{2}$ If $z_0$ is an essential singularity of $$f:U \subset \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$how to prove that $z_0$ can not be a pole of $\large e^{f(z)}$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $f$ holomorph in $U\backslash\{z_0\}$?

Comment: Yes, $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ \exp (z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} $$

is entire.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^m\dfrac{a_k}{(z-z_0)^k}+g(z)$ (Laurent series) with $g$ holomorphic, now $$e^{f(z)}=\left(\prod_{k=1}^me^{\frac{a_k}{(z-z_0)^k}}\right) e^{g(z)}$$
new use the fact that $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ has essential singularity at $0$.